# How to import a JavaScript function from a JavaScript file in the same directory?

Tags: javascript, function

This below is my index.js, the file where i'm trying to call an imported function

```
const mysyn = require('./syntax.js')
router.post("/",(req,res)=>
{
var code = (req.body.Code);
console.log(syn(code));
res.send("POST") 
}
);
```

and this is syntax.js:

```
const syn = function(code)
{
   console.log("In sep html"+ code );
}
module.exports = syn;
```

I tried using ES6 import statement but that didn't work since node throws back the 'Unexpected token {' error. So, How do I come across this?

Answer (score 2):

Your importing and exporting seems to be correct.

Just change this

```
console.log(syn(code));
```

To this

```
console.log(mysyn(code));
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to import a function, you have to export the function.

in syntax.js, you need to export the function like this:

```
module.exports = syn
```

And in your index.js file you have to assign the exported function into a local variable like this:

```js
const mySynFn = require('./syntax.js');
```

Comment: i tried that too. But, i have a doubt, do we have to somewhere use mySynFn while calling the 'syn' function?

Comment: In your first block, just do `const syn = require('./syntax.js');`  You're exporting the whole function so when you require it, that IS the function.  If you want to export more things from that file later, you can export it under a key:

`module.exports = { syn }`

Then when you require it:

`const mySyn = require('./syntax.js'); mySyn.syn();`